# How to filter rows with date in the future with column().search()

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am using function column().search( input [, regex[ , smart[ , caseInsen ]]] ) to get the result for my checkbox(#1)

```
$('#1').click(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    now.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#2, #3").prop('checked', false);
        table.column(5).search('^$|$futureTime', true, false ).draw();
    }
    else {
        table
        .search( '' )
        .columns().search( '' )
        .draw();
    }
});
```

I want the result of column 5 either it is empty or the date inside this column is in the future. The first part works fine. But how can I filter for dates in the future?

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: what's the format of your date (that you show in column 5) ??

Comment: it comes from the database as type "date"

Comment: no i mean (dd-mm-yy) or what .?

Comment: so here is an example: value=2019-12-31

Comment: you can parse date using datejs: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: or using : Date.parse(DateFromDB/DateFromClumn5)

Comment: ok this is the way I can pass the date. i wanna search for all dates that are in the future by using table.column().search() is this possible?

Comment: i just update my post , try it

Answer (score 1):

So this what you gonna do :

```
    $('#1').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#2, #3").prop('checked', false);
        a = table.column(5).data().filter( function ( value, index ) {
            var start = Date.now();
            var dates1 = value.split(".");
            var datecolumn = new Date(dates1[1]+"/"+dates1[0]+"/"+dates1[2]).getTime();
            if(datecolumn > start || value == ''){
                return value;
            }
        } )
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            table.column(5).search(a[i], true, false ).draw();
        }
    }
    else {
        table
    .search( '' )
    .columns().search( '' )
    .draw();
    }
});
```

Comment: ahh thanks for your help :)  this looks nice.if I change this return datecolumn > start ? true : false; to return datecolumn < start ? true : false; nothing changed. So there must be one mistake inside. I see var start, dates1 and datecolumn inside the browser with the wright values ...this is working. Do you know where the mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

So this is working for me:

```
$('#1').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#2, #3").prop('checked', false);
        a = table.column(5).data().filter( function ( value, index ) {
            var start = Date.now();
            var dates1 = value.split(".");
            var datecolumn = new Date(dates1[1]+"/"+dates1[0]+"/"+dates1[2]).getTime();
            if(datecolumn < start){
                return value;
            }
        } )
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            table.column(5).search(a[i], true, false ).draw();
        }
    }
    else {
        table
    .search( '' )
    .columns().search( '' )
    .draw();
    }
});
```

I have to use a for loop because otherwise my table is not shown the result on the website.
Now I have to add rows that are empty. So it should be display rows with date older/newer than today or rows if date value inside the table is empty.

Page with no date value ("enddate):
[image]

Page with all dates:
[image]

Comment: not now. It is shown only rows with date value > today. I will add these rows where date value is empty like this: table.column(5).search("a[i]|^$", true, false ).draw();. But this doesnt work

Comment: you wanna replace empty date with those in the futur ??

Comment: I will filter rows that have empty dates or no date values inside. Only dates in the past should be excluded

Comment: no this is not working for me (if(datecolumn > start || value == ''){)...inside my db the value without date is a null object! with your update I only get rows where date column is > start

Comment: the page with all date the one with no date ,how it display it ??

Comment: I added two pictures for you. Please have a look. With your updated post:if(datecolumn > start || value == ''){ return value; --> I get only the rows with date in the future but not the empty ones

Comment: thanks for your help I posted my solution who is interestet...

Answer (score 0):

I got it! it works with this:

```
$('#1').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#2, #3").prop('checked', false);
        var test = [];
        table.column(5).data().filter( function ( value, index ) {
            var start = Date.now();
            var dates1 = value.split(".");
            var datecolumn = new Date(dates1[1]+"/"+dates1[0]+"/"+dates1[2]).getTime();

            if(datecolumn >= start){
                test.push(value);
            }
            else{
                test.push('^$');
            }
        } )
        console.log(test);
        for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            //console.log(test[i]);
            table.column(5).search(test.join('|'), true, false, true).draw();
        }
    }
    else {
        table
    .search( '' )
    .columns().search( '' )
    .draw();
    }
});
```